# informatica data is not loading into sybase target

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-cloud

I am using Sybase as my target as well as source. It's a direct mapping with a SQL query in source qualifier with some case statements involved. When I run the mapping, data is successfully read but not able to write it to target. I am using sybase 15.4. [image: Here's my error message.]

Comment: You have to check the session log to find the error messages!

Comment: @Samik I am getting error like FnName: Execute--[Sybase][ODBC driver][Sybase IQ] invalide statement  FnName: Execute--[DataDirect][ODBC lib] function sequence error

Comment: There should be more details in the error

Comment: @Samik Got the answer I didn't specify the target table name in session>mapping>Target properties That's was causing the error

Comment: That's great! :-)